# How can i use a sharepoint list as a view in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint site and i create a list on it. I want to join this list with a SQLServer table. I have access to Sharepoint DB in SQLServer and i maked a new table in this DB. My problem is that i can not find my list in Sharepoint DB to join with this new table.
How can i do this.

Comment: Direct access to Sharepoint database is not supported by Microsoft, read this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/841057) for more info. My advice is to write a SSIS or program that read from sharepoint and write to SQL and there write the join query.

Answer (score 0):

You should not access the SharePoint DB even if only for reading. But if you want to do this, there is no documentation on that (no db model). There are some posts about this on the web like [Where does SharePoint store list items](http://sharepoint1on1.blogspot.de/2013/03/where-does-sharepoint-store-list-items.html) or [HOW TO PULL SHAREPOINT LIST DATA FROM SQL SERVER](https://speverything.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/how-to-pull-sharepoint-list-data-from-sql-server/).

```
SELECT
ud.tp_ID
, ud.tp_ListId
, ud.tp_Author
, ud.nvarchar1
, ud.nvarchar2
, ud.nvarchar3
, ud.nvarchar4
, ud.nvarchar5
, ud.nvarchar6
, ud.nvarchar7
, ud.nvarchar8
, ud.nvarchar9
, ud.nvarchar10
, ud.nvarchar11
, ud.nvarchar12
, ud.*
FROM dbo.AllLists l
INNER JOIN dbo.AllUserData ud ON l.tp_ID = ud.tp_ListId
WHERE (ud.tp_ListId = ‘{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}’)
```

In SP2013 the DB model has changed and the data of the lists is now stored as XML in the AllUserData table in the column tp_ColumnSet.

Comment: thanks but there is no table named dbo.Lists and dbo.UserData in WSS_Content. where are these?

Comment: Which SharePoint version do you have? In SP2013 the DB model has changed and the data of the lists is now stored as XML in the `AllUserData` table in the column `tp_ColumnSet`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve my problem and share it to help you. There is a DB in sql server with name `WSS_Content` that you can find the `dbo.AllUserData` table. List data in SharePoint, saved in this table:

[image: image of DB name]

If you select data from this table, you can see a column with the name: `[tp_ColumnSet]` that has data.

You must find out which column has your data and finally create a view by this column's name like this:

```
SELECT    ntext2 AS Url, nvarchar1 AS Title, nvarchar5 AS FileName
FROM         dbo.AllUserData
```